# How to filter on vendor and automaticely take the latest item?

Tags: excel

We have like 200.000 unique articles and i want to create an excel export with Atlas Global software 5.1 from our AX database. When the user fills in a field (vendor) he should get all unique item combinations. Each article have +- 10 dates. The goal is to get the latest date of an unique item. 
As example we have this:

```
Art. nr     Date          Vendor
1000000     22-6-2016     1000
1000000     02-6-2016     1000
1000000     03-6-2016     1000
1000000     06-6-2016     1000
1000000     03-5-2016     1000
2000000     09-3-2016     1000
2000000     08-1-2016     1000
2000000     05-6-2016     1000
2000000     19-6-2016     1000
2000000     03-6-2016     2222
2000000     05-6-2016     2222
4000000     01-5-2016     2222
5410000     03-5-2016     2222
6356622     03-4-2016     2222
2552585     03-3-2016     2222
1551505     03-1-2016     2222
1451556     3-12-2015     2222
0510231     3-11-2015     2222
```

All the combinations here are unique.
When i now fill in a vendor, like 1000 the result should be:

```
1000000    22-6-2016 1000
2000000    19-6-2016 1000
```

That should be the result.
Does anybody knows how i can build this in excel 2013?

Comment: While this is possible in Excel, it's not going to be the best place to do the search. Is it possible to perform the search in your database and have it return the max(date) for each vendor to excel? The sql would be something like `SELECT vendor, max(date) as maxdate FROM vendortable GROUP BY vendor WHERE vendor=<userinputhere>;`

Comment: No, it is for other users and they haven't access to the database... Only to the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most elegant way to solve this is with an array formula (also called a CSE formula since you have to enter it in with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, instead of just Enter).

Assuming your data, with a header, starts in `A1`. And assuming that you user inputs a vendor into cell `F6`. You can enter the following into cell `G6`:

```
=MAX(IF(A2:A19=F6,B2:B19,0))
```

Again, when entering it, hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter. It will get squirrely brackets around the formula to indicate that it's an array formula.

POC:
[image: Screenshot of excel showing the array formula in use]

Essentially, this array formula is doing a `=MaxIf()` type formula, similar to `=SumIf` or `=CountIF()`. It's just that `=MaxIf()` doesn't exist, so we have to write it ourselves with the array formula. It may be a bit slow querying data on a 200000 record sheet though.